# Cannot view Snowflake Stored Procedure Content

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to view the code of the stored procedure in Snowflake ?
When I use desc or get_dll , It only return the title etc but not the content of the code ?
Is it only owner privilege that can read the content of the stored procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_Show_Data"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '';
```

Answer (score 0):

`DESC PROCEDURE` should give you the body as well ( as long as you call it properly ; with right param types), but how about querying the `routine` table :

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name'
  AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'your_procedure_name';
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will try your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the stored procedure described in the question is empty - so it's no surprise that `desc` comes empty too.

If you have the right privileges - like being the owner on a just created sp - you should be able to see the body (just make sure there is a body).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_Show_Data"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
select 1;
';

desc procedure "SP_Show_Data"();
```

[image]

You could also be dealing with a `secure` stored procedure that hides its body from roles unauthorized to see it:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/secure-udf-procedure#limiting-the-visibility-of-a-udf-or-procedure-definition

Comment: Hi 
Thank you for your help.
We found out we have to be the owner of the script to be able to view the content.